# How to use deep selector in scss in vue

Tags: vue.js

How to use deep selector in scss in vue?

The code below not work.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.a{
 &>>>.b{
  ...
 }
}
</style>
```

A deep selector like `>>>` in `css` but in `scss` inside vue single file component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue, and i eventually fix this using `::v-deep` as stated here:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-input {
  ::v-deep .v-text-field__details {
    min-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    .v-messages {
      min-height: 0;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 9):

From the vue docs:

"Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse `>>>` properly. In those cases you can use the `/deep/` combinator instead - it's an alias for `>>>` and works exactly the same."

So try this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.a {
 /deep/ .b {
  ...
 }
}
</style>
```

Comment: This will change/has changed, depending on your implementation of SCSS.
If you're using `dart-sass` then this will **not** work. You need to use `::v-deep` instead [GH comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3399#issuecomment-466319019).
If you're using `node-sass` then you'll be ok to continue using `/deep/` until they catch up and remove support for it too.

Comment: Yeah, this just results in a SassError that it was expecting a selection instead of a `/` at the start of `/deep/`